# Amazon EC2 Deployment with Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5.3

I have a new ec2 instance of amazon. I want to deploy my laravel application from beanstalk application.

How can I do that ? I searched lot of in web and found any great solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide if you want to deploy your application to a plain EC2 instance or if you want to use Beanstalk.

If you want to use Beanstalk than you don't need to create an EC2 instance yourself. Beanstalk will do that for you.

If you search for beanstalk laravel the first hit will point you to: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html

Comment: I want to deploy to plain ec2 instance.

Comment: @Jishad then you can't use Elastic Beanstalk